# c++/error: no matching function for call to calcGrossWages()

Tags: c++, arrays, function, compiler-errors, pass-by-reference

```
/**************************************************************************************
 *  The program should display each employee number                                   *
 *  ask the user to enter that employee’s hours and pay rate.                         *
 *  It should then calculate the gross wages for that employee(hours times pay rate)  *
 *  store them in the wages array.                                                    *
 *  After the data has been entered for all the employees,                            *
 *  the program should display each employee’s identification number and gross wages. *
 **************************************************************************************/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 


const int Num_Employees = 7;  // global constant of # of employees 

int empId[Num_Employees] = {5658846, 4520125, 785122, 877541, 8451277, 1302850, 7580489}; // array of Employee ID #'s 
int hours[7];       // empty array of 7 possible values for employee hours 
double payRate[7];  // empty array of 7 possible values for employee pay rates 
double wages[7];    // empty array of 7 possible values for employees wages (hours * pay rate)

void calcGrossWages(int[],  double[], double[]); // calculate gross wages prototype



int main() {


    // Employees
    for(int i= 0; i< Num_Employees; i++) {

        cout << "Your ID is: " << "" << empId[i] << endl; // displays each employee # 

        cout << "How many hours did you work?";  

        cin >> hours[i];



        cout << "What was your payRate?" << endl;

        cout <<"$";

        cin >> payRate[i]; 
    }

        /*Calculate the gross wages*/

    for(int i = 0; i < Num_Employees; i++) {

        wages[i] = calcGrossWages(hours[i], payRate[i], wages[i]);


    }

    }



//******************************************************************************
//* Definition of calcGrossWages function                                      *
//* This function calculates the employees Wages                               *
//* Wages are calculated by the # of hours worked by each employee             *
//* multiplied by their enter pay rate                                         *
// *****************************************************************************

void calcGrossWages(int hours[], double payRate[], double wages[]) 
{
    for (int i= 0; i< Num_Employees; i++) {

          wages[i] = hours[i] * payRate[i];

    }





}
```

Questions:

How to pass a array as a parameter into a function properly, allowing one to be able to enter values in an empty array?

Why do I get an error saying no matching function for call 'calcGrossWages'

Comment: `calcGrossWages(hours[i], payRate[i], wages[i]);` calls with plain  `double` arguments rather than arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass arrays in  **calcGrossWages** instead of just pass element of array and don't need loop in main for calling **calcGrossWages**

```
 /********************************************************************************   ******
 *  The program should display each employee    number                                   *
 *  ask the user to enter that employee’s hours and pay     rate.                         *
 *  It should then calculate the gross wages for that employee(hours times pay  rate)  *
 *  store them in the wages     array.                                                    *
 *  After the data has been entered for all the     employees,                            *
 *  the program should display each employee’s identification number and gross  wages. *
 ********************************************************************************   ******/

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std; 


const int Num_Employees = 7;  // global constant of # of employees 

int empId[Num_Employees] = {5658846, 4520125, 785122, 877541, 8451277, 1302850,     7580489}; // array of Employee ID #'s 
int hours[7];       // empty array of 7 possible values for employee hours 
double payRate[7];  // empty array of 7 possible values for employee pay rates 
double wages[7];    // empty array of 7 possible values for employees wages (   hours * pay rate)

void calcGrossWages(int[],  double[], double[]); // calculate gross wages   prototype



int main() {


    // Employees
    for(int i= 0; i< Num_Employees; i++) {

        cout << "Your ID is: " << "" << empId[i] << endl; // displays each  employee # 

        cout << "How many hours did you work?";  

        cin >> hours[i];



        cout << "What was your payRate?" << endl;

        cout <<"$";

        cin >> payRate[i]; 
    }

        /*Calculate the gross wages*/

    calcGrossWages(hours, payRate, wages);

    }




//******************************************************************************
//* Definition of calcGrossWages function                                      *
//* This function calculates the employees Wages                               *
//* Wages are calculated by the # of hours worked by each employee             *
//* multiplied by their enter pay rate                                         *
// *****************************************************************************

void calcGrossWages(int hours[], double payRate[], double wages[]) 
{
    for (int i= 0; i< Num_Employees; i++) {

          wages[i] = hours[i] * payRate[i];

    }





}
```

Comment: Thank you I have no clue why I thought I should run a for loop to call the function.

Answer (score 0):

`array[i]` is one array element, not the entire array; you're trying to pass `int`s and `double`s instead of arrays of them.

Since the arrays' names are `hours`, `payRate`, and `wages`, you call the function like this:

```
/*Calculate the gross wages*/
calcGrossWages(hours, payRate, wages)
```

You don't need a loop since the function already handles the entire arrays, and the function doesn't return anything (the result is stored in `wages`).

(And as a side note, those variables should be local to `main`, not global.)